# Back to previous fragment on onBackPressed in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, onbackpressed

I'm new to Android development and developing an application using Android's default Navigation drawer layout.

I'm using fragment in the application.

I want to get back to previous fragment when back button is pressed on next fragment.
The onBackPress must implement following functions

1. Get back to previous fragment when on next fragment
2. Close drawer when navigation drawer is open
3. Exit app on double back press when in fragment1

**This is what my code is in MainActivity
    while creating new fragment**

```
// replacing the fragment
if (fragment != null) {
     FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
     ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
  ft.commit();
}
```

**onBackPress**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

But this is not working and on pressing back exits the application except when Navigation drawer is open it is closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not adding the fragment to the backstack.  You just have to do

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
 .addToBackStack(null);
 .commit();
```

And since the Backstack is actually handled by the back button, you do not need to handle this scenario in `onBackPressed()`, so you can change it to just:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: adding `.addToBackStack(null);` is not working. After adding this line, on first Back button press, nothing happens and on second click the application exits

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the `Fragment` in your `FragmentTransaction` to the backstack.

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
     ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).addtoBackStack(null).commit();
```

By giving the tag `null` they all get grouped by that tag. So if you need to close them all together you can do so or navigate to a certain one.

I also would not use `replace()`, because that one is incredibly buggy with the backstack.

Try to use `remove()` and then `add()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should add your fragment to the back stack and modify your code this way:

```
// this variable is needed to know how many times the back key has been pressed.
// It is incremented and reset accordingly to the logic you described
int mBackPressCount = 0;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
            // if there are no fragments in your back stack check the mBackPressCount
            if (mBackPressCount++ > 0) {
                // if you pressed back for the second time this line will terminate the activity
                super.onBackPressed();
            } 
        } else {
            // this line will pop the fragment from the back stack,
            // no need to pop it manually
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Add the fragment to the back stack:

```
if (fragment != null) {
     FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
     ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
     ft.addToBackStack(null);
     ft.commit();

     // when you add a fragment you should reset the back press count
     mBackPressCount = 0;
}
```

Reset mBackPressCount when open and close the drawer. If you have pressed the back key once and you open the drawer the counter has to be set to 0 again.

```
DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        mBackPressCount = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
        mBackPressCount = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {

    }
});
```

Comment: where to insert the 3rd code segment ? `drawerLayout` is an object of `DrawerLayout` ?

Comment: you can put it in the onCreate method. Modified the snippet. However I suggest to use data binding in order to avoid all these findViewById calls (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html)

Comment: I did what you said, but on 2nd fragment it is accepting 3 times back press and nothing happens and on 3rd key press, the application exits

Comment: the behaviour you should obtain would be: on the second fragment, when you press back the fragment is popped out, then if you press back for two times it should exit (remember also to not add the first fragment to the back stack)